# Should I use a descriptor class or a property factory?

Tags: python, properties, descriptor

Say I have a class and I want to make a lot of similar "property-style" attributes. For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, val):
        self.update()
        self._foo = val

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, val):
        self.update()
        self._bar = val

    @property
    def baz(self):
        return self._baz

    @baz.setter
    def baz(self, val):
        self.update()
        self._baz = val

    def update(self):
        print "Updating..."
```

Obviously there is a lot of repetition here and it'd be nice to factor that out. One way would be to make a function that returns a property:

```
def create_property(var):
    def _setter(self, val):
        self.update()
        setattr(self, '_' + var, val)

    def _getter(self):
        return getattr(self, '_' + var)

    return property(_getter, _setter)

class Foo(object):
    foo = create_property("foo")
    bar = create_property("bar")
    baz = create_property("baz")

    def update(self):
        print "Updating..."
```

Alternatively I could write a descriptor class:

```
class UpdateOnChange(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        try:
            return self.data[instance]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError("attribute not set")

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.update()
        self.data[instance] = value

class Foo(object):
    foo = UpdateOnChange()
    bar = UpdateOnChange()
    baz = UpdateOnChange()

    def update(self):
        print "Updating"
```

Which is best/fastest/most Pythonic?

Comment: Descriptors are there for precisely this. So, *in my opinion*, you should use descriptors. I italicized this on purpose to highlight that this is mostly opinion based. Voting to put on hold, as primarily opinion based

Comment: I'd recommend the decorator too.  Though if you combined that with a metaclass, you could automatically ingest the names of the class variables to construct the descriptor, thereby obviating the need for the `self.data` dictionary.  That would be slightly better for memory and performance overhead, but probably more importantly, you wouldn't ever have to deal with key collisions or odd behavior in the case the referent dies.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the descriptor idea and mixing it with a metaclass, as I mentioned in the comments.

```
class UpdateOnChange(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        try:
            return getattr(instance, self._name)
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError('%s has no attribute %s.' % (instance, self.name))

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # Assume first assignment is initialization and does not require update.
        if not hasattr(instance, self._name):
            setattr(instance, self._name, value)
        else:
            instance.update()
            setattr(instance, self._name, value)

class UpdateOnChangeMeta(type):

     def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
         for attr_name in attrs:
             if attrs[attr_name] == UpdateOnChange:
                 attrs[attr_name] = UpdateOnChange(attr_name)
         return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class Foo(object):

    __metaclass__ = UpdateOnChangeMeta
    foo = UpdateOnChange
    bar = UpdateOnChange
    baz = UpdateOnChange

    def update(self):
        print "Updating"
```